# How to delete particular value from JSON in user preference of Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

When I use the following link

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/people/admin/preferences?pf=org.my
```

it returns a json structure like this

```
{"org": 
    {"ivory": 
        {"share": 
            {"site": 
                {"search": 
                    {"dashlet": 
                        {"component-1-1": 
                            {"search-definition": 
                                {"fromdate": "01\/02\/2015", 
                                 "author": "jhone", 
                                 "todate": "30\/04\/2015", 
                                 "term": "pensions"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I delete **author** section from this JSON?

Comment: Use this line on controller  of alfresco                                                                                                     var connector = remote.connect("alfresco"); 
var pp = "/api/people/admin/preferences?pf=org.site";
connector.del(pp);

Answer (score 0):

The preferences REST API has a [delete webscript](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/person/person.delete.desc.xml). To delete an item from the preferences store, make sure the filter specified in the *pf* parameter identifies **just** the item you want to delete and then call it with a HTTP delete method.

E.g. a HTTP GET to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/people/admin/preferences?pf=org.alfresco.share.sites.favourites.12345
```

will return true if that site is favourited. To remove it from the favourites, make a HTTP DELETE request for the same URL.